# regular expression not working on the datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The date in my table looks like **2010-06-16 00:00:00.000**

When I use the below regular expression, no rows get selected.

```
select mydate from mytable where mydate like '2010%'
```

However, when I use this one, rows do get selected correctly.

```
select mydate from mytable where mydate like '%2010%'
```

So, I thought that probably leading white spaces are getting added. To take those into account, I used the below query. But this doesn't work either.

```
select mydate from mytable where LTRIM(RTRIM(mydate)) like '2010%'
```

Since the first one works, it means, that there is something before the 2010? What else apart from white spaces, could it be? I tried pasting it onto a text file, and don't see anything.

Comment: what is the datatype of `mydate`

Comment: @NoDisplayName , it's datetime

Comment: Just to clarify, what you've done here is a wildcard expression, not a regular expression. SQL Server does not natively support regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `datatype` is `Datetime` you should use `Year()` function to filter the rows instead of `like`. You should not use `like` operator to filter the data from `Datetime` type.

If the `datatype` is `Datetime` then you won't be having `leading` or `trailing` spaces.

You do have appropriate `Date` functions in `Sql Server` use those to filter the rows.

```
select mydate from mytable where year(mydate) = 2010
```

or even `Datepart`

```
select mydate from mytable where Datepart(YYYY,mydate) = 2010
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert `datetime` that first in `varchar` to use `like`

```
select mydate from mytable
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),mydate,120) like '2010%'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26ecfb/3)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use just date range fetches, for example

> select mydate from mytable where mydate >= '20100101' and mydate < '20110101'

Using functions for the column (e.g. year(mydate)) is not a good idea because then indexes can't be used. Using 'between' can also cause problems with datetime columns because the time part can cause you to accidentally leave out rows.

The reason you found something with your search is probably due to typecasting the date into varchar before comparison, and format is such that the year is at the end, but please don't use that.